# Grafana flow mode service_graphs

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-variable, grafana-api

I am using flow mode to configure my grafana agent.
In the traditional modo I can see here: https://grafana.com/docs/tempo/latest/configuration/grafana-agent/service-graphs/, how can enable service graph.
But I  do not how can configure service graph in flow mode (config.river).

I can find the trace section in the new configuration style.